# Laravel artisan error:processutils

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-artisan

```
In Application.php line 104:
Class 'Illuminate\Support\ProcessUtils' not found
```

every time I excute artisan in my project this problem appears, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you used `ProcessUtils` in your custom command (this is probably what you did) you should import it from valid namespace. Add:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessUtils;
```

before line:

```
class ....
```

Now it seems you haven't imported it or you imported in from invalid namespace because there is no `Illuminate\Support\ProcessUtils` class but there is `Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessUtils` class.